# For loop with value manipulation in batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%G IN (C:\Users\asian\Desktop\FOR_LOOP\1sv1.csV) do echo %%G,%%H,%%I >> 1.csv
```

output:

```
20030701,1001,456.000000 
20030701,1002,459.000000 
20030701,1003,450.000000 
20030701,1004,456.000000 
20030701,1005,459.000000
```

my Query is that i want to divide value for `%%I variable(456.000000)`
output should be like this:

```
20030701,1001,228.000000 
20030701,1002,229.5.000000 
20030701,1003,225.000000 
20030701,1004,228.000000 
20030701,1005,229.5.000000
```

Comment: You *can* do maths with batch files (see `set /?`), but it would probably be waaaay easier if you could use python, or just a spreadsheet and a formula..

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(FOR /F "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%G IN (C:\Users\asian\Desktop\FOR_LOOP\1sv1.csV) do (
    set /a "i=%%I*5"
    echo %%G,%%H,!i:~0,-1!.!i:~-1!00000
)) > 1.csv
endlocal
```

Batch arithmetics has no decimals. So, to handle it, the value is multiplied by 10 (to gain an aditional position) and divided by 2 (from OP). Then, the value is splitted as the last digit is the first decimal.